# Notepad++ complex conditional search regex

Tags: regex, replace, conditional-statements, notepad++

I have a database SQL followed by a bunch of statements to collect statistics. I'd like to search the SQL for  a specific join and find all corresponding collect statistics statements and then modify them  to remove extraneous chars to finally extract a useful  bunch of statements
 Input

```
          select tbd.cola , tba.a, tbx.b, 
                                   tbc.r,
                             tbx.c ,
                       case when yada ya then tbx.c + xyz else 'daddy' end as nicecol
                       , tbx.g
               from 
               tbd  join tba on tbd.cola  =   tba.colb 
                  left join
               tbx on tbx.colp= tba.colp left join
               tbc on tbc.colfff=tbx.colm join......


        /*this is followed by a bunch of statements in format */
            ---- "collect stats column (cola,colbxx) 
    on tbd ( medium strong )" 
            ----      "collect stats column (colfff) on tbc ( not 
    strong )" 
          ----   "collect stats column ( colddsdsd) on tbc (    very strong  )" 
                 ----"collect stats col (yada,secretxxx,xxx) on tbx ( strong ) "

        note the spacing between  follows logic 
                 (/s*medium|not|very/s*strong/s*)
        same thing for 
         ----   "collect stats column 

        in other words - variable spacing between all the words.
 No consistent spacing pattern and 
the statements arbitrarily span between multiple lines or squeeze in a single line.
```

What  I'd like to do is :

- Search for column names being joined `e.g. tbd.cola  =   tba.colb`
- Then look for these column names in the collect statistics statements so in our case 
  `cola  colp colm colfff` are they join column names that come from

  `tbd  join tba on tbd.cola  =   tba.colb 
                    left join
                 tbx on tbx.colp= tba.colp left join
                 tbc on tbc.colfff=tbx.colm`
  we search for these in the collect stats statements and the following qualify

  `---- "collect stats column (cola,colbxx) on tbd ( medium strong )" 
          ----      "collect stats column (colfff) on tbc ( not strong )"`
- Next the statements have to be "purified" so the extraneous chars & writing around em are removed.The desirable output format is below

  `collect stats column (cola,colbxx) on tbd;`
  `collect stats column (colfff) on tbc ;` 

  remove the `---- "` pattern `[-]+?"` and 
  replace `( <string with or without space and with variable spaces around it> )"` of the form `( not strong )"` with `;`

What I did was multistep process. I could manage the 3rd part using 
`"\s*([^"]+ strong\s*)\)`

so that is  like done but I am looking for a conditional select approach here. Need help w/ the 1st two.

 there is no  need to use boundaries to select the collect stats statement. I could select that part using my mouse and then  work a regex in the selected part only 

 
The logic would be to

- search for `join\s*tablename.column\s*\=\s*tablename.column` pattern. The `\=` has `=` escaped
- collect all matching column names into a buffer
- Then create boundaries or physically select the part where collect statistics statement begins.
- Run the select column list through the bunch of collect stats statements to see which qualify.
  if there is a column combination like `collect stats column (cola,colbxx)` and only `cola` is a join column - that is also selected since one of em cols is a join column
- Finally we have a shortlisted collect statistics statement bunch on which we run the last regex  ( logic `"\s*([^"]+ strong\s*)\)`)to  rid it off extraneous characters.
- We can break this operation into 2 components. 1st part is the conditional search. Search for joined column names in the collect statistics area. Search results get copied and pasted into another work area  ( a new file )  and then we run the last part above on this selected  file.

Comment: I'm going to look for something, but this should be challenging ^^ Just one thing : could you add an example of what you want at the end (I'm not sure to get it right) ? If I understand correctly, `---- "collect stats column (cola,colbxx) on tbd ( medium strong )"` must become `collect stats column (cola,colbxx) on tbd;` but `----   "collect stats column ( colddsdsd) on tbc (    very strong  )"` should stay untouched because `colddsdsd` (or `cold` followed by `dsdsd`) is not a a joined col ?

Comment: Also, is `colbxx` `colb` with `x`'s appended to its name, or a totally different column ?

Comment: Yes the  latter `"collect stats column ( colddsdsd) on tbc ( very strong )"` should not even come up   as  a shortlisted  collect stats statement to modify since there are no joined columns. The 1st transformation is correct .On the last comment `colbxx colb`  is a combination of 2 columns whose stats I want.Since `colb` is a joined column - I will need it and it qualifies. Sorry if I wasnt clear. -TY

Comment: Oh ok I think I got it. You want to keep only `collect stats column (cola,colbxx) on tbd;` (and other statements containing joined columns) and remove everything else ?

Comment: Yes that would work. I outlined  a plausible pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found something ! It works for the example you gave, but I can't have anticipated all possibilities, so tell me if it works for you.
It uses 2 substitutions. Make sure you checked regular expression, and the box next to it (saying something like ". matches new lines")
**First substitution :**
Replace this :
`join\s+\w+\s+on\s+\w+\.(\w+)\b\s*=\s*\w+\.(\w+)\b(?=.*-+\s+"([^"]+(?:\1|\2)[^"]+)(\s)+\([^)]+\)")|.`
By this :
`\3\4`
**Second substitution :**
Replace this :
`(collect.*?)\s+(on\s\w+)\s`
By this :
`\1 \2;\n

---

**Demo**
First substitution : [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FkBMXv/1)
Second substitution : [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/emHZ86/1)

---

**Explanations**
The regex is based on a alternation. The first part is
`join\s+\w+\s+on\s+\w+\.(\w+)\b\s*=\s*\w+\.(\w+)\b(?=.*-+\s+"([^"]+(?:\1|\2)[^"]+)(\s)+\([^)]+\)")`
`join\s+\w+\s+on\s+\w+\.(\w+)\b\s*=\s*\w+\.(\w+)\b` matches a string built like that : *join tbname on tbname.cola = tbname.colb*. Note that spaces around the `=` are optional and the names of cola and colb are captured for future use.
`(?=.*-+\s+"([^"]+(?:\1|\2)[^"]+)(\s)+\([^)]+\)")` allows the precedent match only if there is later in the file a string like *---- "[...] [cola OR colb] [...] ([...])"*, or in other words, a string beginning with multiples `-`, then 1 or more spaces and a `"`, ending with a pair of `()` and a `"`, and containing either `cola` or `colb` (or both).
It will look for a match like that at each position in the file, and for each position, if it does not match, it will go to the second part of the alternation, which is `.` (anything). So in the end, it will match the whole file, but if it matched some joined columns, capturing groups will contain something which is then written in the file through the replacement `\3\4`
The second substitution is just a reformatting of the lines kept.

---

**Notes**

- I could do it with a single substitution, but it would be much more
  ugly.
- It might be strange, I had to erase the text that need to be kept at the end and rewrite it. The reason is Notepad++ does not allow lookbehinds to have a non defined size.
- Depending on the size of your file, the first substitution might take much more time that for the example. I don't know how Notepad++ reacts when it takes too much time, but it might crash... If it is the case, we will have to split the process into multiples smaller substitutions.

Comment: HI TY again but if I put the above in Notepad++ or even the actual SQL , collect stats in N++ , it will literally select EVERY letter and in fact  doing a  ^ H as above will Clear the entire  file. There is nothing left in there. Result of substitution is empty  file.

Comment: @user1874594 That's weird... It means it didn't find a single joined column which is referenced later in a collect statement... Did you check the ". matches new lines" box ?

Comment: @user1874594 At least, I know it works with the example you provided. Can you try with it, to be sure nothing is missing ?

Comment: yes I did she on the Java applet for regex demo it does work . but it will not work with actual Notepad software you can try that out

Comment: @user1874594 I actually only tried on Notepad++. After the substitution, your file is completely empty, or, is filled with only new lines ?

Comment: hi the file is completely empty

Comment: @user1874594 I don't understand how it's possible... It works fine with my Notepad++. There must be something you're doing wrong, I don't see why it would work with me and not with you... Make sure you use the latest version of notepad++. I don't think it will change anything, but I'm out of options, here...

Comment: I am still hitting the same exp. I think this is because the alternative that follows *OR match everything in there* this part -->  `|.`  The precedent expression does not choose anything and the 2nd part `|.` kicks in chooses everything. This logic works on the search for column name component `JOIN(.*?)ON\s+\w+.\w+\s*=\w+.\w+`  *select everything from JOIN to 1st instance of ON* & then on I am giving pattern - I gotto 'go slow' after the ON part since I need to capture the Column list in some kind of buffer. Can you explain me a bit more about capturing the col list in a buffer-I'd be then

Comment: able to put something togather myself.

Comment: @user1874594 I'll add an explanation about a regex in my answer